# Problema con floatval() en PHP

Tags: php, jquery, float

Tengo problemas con el `floatval()`, me devuelve números incorrectos, obtengo los arrays `indices, cant y precios` como parámetros enviados por jquery con `.load` obtenidos de inputs, no hay ningún problema hasta ahí, a pesar de que los arrays los envío como enteros y floats, no como strings, sin embargo en php al llamarlos los toma como string. Al convertir los enteros con intval no tengo problemas, el problema está en `floatval()`:

```
$producto[0]=intval($_REQUEST['indices'][0]);
$producto[1]=intval($_REQUEST['cant'][0]);
$producto[2]=floatval($_REQUEST['precios'][0]);
$productos[]=$producto;
$productos=json_encode($productos);
```

Sin el `floatval()` me devuelve esto: `[[2,1,"2.3"]]`

Con `floatval()` me devuelve esto: `[[2,1,2.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875]]`

Lo que quiero es esto: `[[2,1,2.3]]`

El problema sucede con 2.3 o 2.6 por ejemplo, pero con 1.5 no da problemas, no entiendo la razón, intenté también con `(float)` pero da el mismo resultado, y con `number_format` me devuelve string, también dividí entre 1, multipliqué por 1, pero el resultado es el mismo que `floatval`.

Con 2.6: `[[2,1,2.600000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625]]`

Con 1.5: `[[2,1,1.5]]`

PD: Por cierto, logré lo que quiero poniendo `$productos=str_replace('"', '', $productos);` después del `json_encode`, pero el punto es por qué se da un error tan raro en `floatval()`.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo puedes intentar usar la función round e indicarle cuantos decimales quieres. Lo probé poniendo los números que le pasas y funciono. Quedo atento. Adicionalmente te dejo la documentación de la función round.
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.round.php

```
$producto[0]=intval($_REQUEST['indices'][0]);
$producto[1]=intval($_REQUEST['cant'][0]);
$producto[2]=round(floatval($_REQUEST['precios'][0]),1);
$productos[]=$producto;
$productos=json_encode($productos);
```

Comment: Buena idea, gracias

Comment: Si mi respuesta te fue útil podrías votar positivo Bro, te lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

[En esta página del manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.float.php) habla de posibles errores que pueden ocurren en algunos casos por la conversión entre valores de base 10 y base 2, que parece que es lo que está ocurriendo en tu caso.

Como dices en tu pregunta que no te ha funcionado correctamente usando `(float)`, y que con `number_format` te sigue devolviendo el valor como cadena, podrías usar las 2 conjuntamente para obtener el resultado (me parece un poco "cochinada" pero en casos de emergencia....). Sería algo así:

```
$producto[2]=(float)number_format($_REQUEST['precios'][0], 1);
```

A ver si te puede servir

Comment: Probé como lo pusiste pero me devuelve String

Comment: No lo había probado. Si le cambias el orden te valdría (comprobado que devuelve número)